# retrieve data from text area in flex table using google apps script

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a flextable where a column in each row has a text area wwhich is named according to the row number . I want to retrieve data from each text area and add it to the spreadsheet. Following doesn't work:
    e.parameter.('name'+row);
Can anybody please suggest me a way to do this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

brackets and no dot - 
`e.parameter['name'+row];`

Comment: You might also want to do `row.toString()` if it is an integer